# enriched fuel in reactors

Tags: nuclear-physics, neutrons

Why is it not possible to use hot neutrons and enriched fuel in reactors?

It works in fast reactors where the enriched fuel is necessary. Fast hot neutrons wouldn't give energy to non-enriched fuel. Is that right?

Why the efficiency of the fission reaction is decreased by slow neutrons when there are lots of isotopes of uranium 235 in fuel? Why aren't slow neutrons able to split enriched fuel?

Comment: Slow neutrons work just fine on U235. Not sure really what the question is here.

Comment: I am asking why hot neutrons work not fine.

Comment: Well, that isn’t what your last paragraph asks. Please edit to clarify.

Comment: So, go to your favorite ENDF (evaluated nuclear data files) provider. Compare fission cross sections for 235U and 238U. That will give you some hint.